# Where does qt creator save my projects

Tags: qt, qt-creator

Somebody knows where [qt creator](http://qt.nokia.com/products) (in which directory) saves my projects?

Comment: You may want to change your post title from qt to qt creator.

Comment: @Victor Py: I just changed that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can choose in which directory your project will reside when you create a new project. You have two options to choose from:

- `Name` (the name of the project)
- `Create in` (the directory where to save the project)

Version `1.3.0` on `Windows XP` saves by default in `C:\Documents and Settings\your_username\My Documents`.